Migrar proyecto desde .NET Framework 4.5 a .NET Standar 2.0
Tengo un proyecto .NET Framework 4.5 y quiero migrarlo a la versión de .NET Standar 2.0
Uno de los problemas que tengo es al abrir el proyecto. Obtengo esta ventana:

Si se actualiza el proyecto a .NET Framework 4.8, se obtienen una serie de errores:

Si se opta por descargar el paquete de compatibilidad .NET Framework 4.5 obtengo esto:

El caso es que quiero directamente migrar el proyecto a .NET Standard 2.0.
Buscando en internet proponen simplemente actualizar el .csproj, hacer que el TargetFramework apunte a .NET Standard 2.0 y luego utilizar NuGet para actualizar paquetes.
He codigo mi .csproj y he hecho que apunte a .NET Standar 2.0:

pero al intentar abrir las propiedades del proyecto obtengo el siguiente error en pantalla

12/04/2024 10:42:18
Recoverable
System.ArgumentException: Expected 1 values for property Build::DefineConstants, but got 0. The property page may not be defined for all configurations.
Nombre del parámetro: values
   en Microsoft.Requires.Argument(Boolean condition, String parameterName, ValidationInterpolatedStringHandler& message)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.Property.Update(ImmutableArray`1 values)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.Property..ctor(PropertyMetadata metadata, ImmutableArray`1 values, PropertyContext context, ImmutableHashSet`1 varyByDimensions)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.PropertyContextFactoryBase.ToProperty(IUIPropertySnapshot property, Page page, Category category, Int32 order, PropertyContext propertyContext, IPropertyEditorRegistry propertyEditorRegistry)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<HandleDataAsync>g__CreateProperties|14_5(<>c__DisplayClass14_0& )
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<HandleDataAsync>g__ProcessInitialData|14_1(<>c__DisplayClass14_0& )

He intentado buscar en internet para corregir este error y he dado con este post, pero tampoco me ha servido de mucho.
¿Qué otros pasos o qué tengo que corregir para migrar el proyecto a .NET Standard 2.0?
